# Convert array to string in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector

I have a vector `a = [1 2 3 4 5]` how would I make it so b = '12345'?

I have tried `b = num2str(a)` but it outputs `1 2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the format in [`num2str`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), much as you would in C's function `sprintf`:

```
b = num2str(a,'%i');
```

Or use [`sprintf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
b = sprintf('%i',a);
```

If `a` contains only single-digit numbers, you can also convert to [char](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) directly:

```
b = char(a+'0');
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luis for helping me with this, that was exactly what I was looking for. Another question I have is how would I make the first element of c have this value? Such as c(1) = 12345?

Comment: I understood from your question that the desired result `'12345'` was a string, not a number (otherwise use [Shai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26954525/2586922) less the `num2str` part). So you want to assign a _string_ to the first element of a variable `c`? If `c` has to store other strings of possibly different lengths, `c` should be a cell array; and you'd just do `c{1} = b`

Comment: Thank you Luis Mendo and Shai for your inputs. Sorry I should of been more clear with my first question as I ultimately wanted the output from the array a to be a string '12345' so I could put it into a position of another array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert yor vector to a single number first (assuming **all** elements are in range 0..9):

```
a = 1:5;
num = ( 10.^((numel(a)-1):-1:0) ) * a'; %'
b = num2str( num )
```

You can try this code [here](http://ideone.com/s3uSoR).